# How to give access to an update page to one particular user only?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a user entity and later I want to allow the users to update their details. I do this by sending to a route http://localhost:8000/update/{id}
I want to make this page to be accessed by that owner of the profile only. For an instance, if the user with the id 20 is logged in, he should have access to only http://localhost:8000/update/20 and should not allow to access someone else's. How to do this in symfony 4?

Comment: Take a look at [Symfony security voters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html).

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, you can get the current logged in user by the following code.
$this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

Answer (score -1):

Use session variables, so that it is unique only to the user and the user cannot access other user's pages.
It is similar to the way in which when one user is logged in, he can't access other accounts.
That is also done using session variables.
[Session variables in symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html)

Comment: I think you may have left out just a couple of details.  I suspect you will need just a tad bit more code than a session variable.  I sort of think that using the Symfony security system for authorization would make more sense.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you but using sessions would be enough for doing a basic one.

Comment: Thank you very much all. It helped.